# Assertion Error while performing easymock on junit

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am facing following exception while running my test case. Please help.

The code :

```
       @Test
       public void shouldSaveTypedOrder() throws Exception {
           mockControl.replay();
           sampleDto.setId(null);
           Sample savedDto = sampleDao.save(sampleDto);
           mockControl.verify();
           assertThat(savedDto).isEqualTo(sampleDto);
       }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Unexpected method call DataSource.getConnection():
    at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
    at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:85)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.TableMetaDataProviderFactory.createMetaDataProvider(TableMetaDataProviderFactory.java:63)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.TableMetaDataContext.processMetaData(TableMetaDataContext.java:205)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.compileInternal(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:280)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.compile(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:265)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.checkCompiled(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:316)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.AbstractJdbcInsert.doExecuteAndReturnKey(AbstractJdbcInsert.java:391)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert.executeAndReturnKey(SimpleJdbcInsert.java:126)
    at com.inetwork.common.dao.BaseDaoImpl.insert(BaseDaoImpl.java:121)
    at com.inetwork.common.dao.notification.TypedOrderDao.save(TypedOrderDao.java:85)
    at com.inetwork.common.dao.notification.TypedOrderDaoTest.shouldSaveTypedOrder(TypedOrderDaoTest.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAO tries to get the connection to the DataSource in BaseDaoImpl's insert method on line 121.

```
 com.inetwork.common.dao.BaseDaoImpl.insert(BaseDaoImpl.java:121)
```

You probably don't want to connect to a real database.

You will need to also somehow mock the Connection object and have the DataSource.getConnection() method return your mock.